# Template class definition when typename is templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, boost-asio, c++20

I'm realizing a simple server backend which can work with tcp and unix sockets.
Here is the listener block:

```cpp
static asio::awaitable<void> listener() {
    const auto executor = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor(executor, asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint(socket_file_));

    for (;;) {
        auto socket = co_await acceptor.async_accept(asio::use_awaitable);
        ...
```

After that the session is initializing by creating an instance of `Session` class with this `socket`.

In this case `socket` has type `asio::local::stream_protocol::socket`, but in tcp case the type will be `asio::ip::tcp::socket`.
All of them has one base class - `asio::basic_stream_socket` and I want to realize generic `Session` class:

```cpp
template <typename Protocol, typename Executor>
class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session<Protocol, Executor>> {
    using Socket = asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol, Executor>;

public:
    explicit Session(Socket sock) : socket_(std::move(sock)) {}

    void start() {
        co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
                 [self = this->shared_from_this()] { return self->reader(); },
                 asio::detached);
    }

private:
    Socket socket_;

    asio::awaitable<void> reader() {
        ...
```

In this realization I must to explicitly specify types `Protocol` and `Executor` in `listener` method:

```cpp
    std::make_shared<Session<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::any_io_executor>>(std::move(socket))->start();
```

or

```cpp
    std::make_shared<Session<decltype(socket)::protocol_type, decltype(socket)::executor_type>>(std::move(socket))->start();
```

what looks cumbersome and seems redundant.

Is there any way to optimize the `Session` class template definition?

Comment: Why is Session derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this`? It doesn't seem relevant to your question or am I missing something?

Comment: @joergbrech It's very relevant as it is the dominant pattern to achieve lifetime management for asynchronous sessions in Asio

Comment: Of course we don't see the code, but does your Session care about the protocol? I'd consider just templating on the concrete parameters instead of indirectly via template arguments. I think what you want to do can be done, but will lead to unnecessarily complicated templates. I remember doing a similar answer for UPD/TCP earlier will find a link. Found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992182/is-there-a-problem-with-the-socket-i-wrote-for-boostsocket-for-the-simplifyin/71993476#71993476

Comment: @sehe, yes, I do not care about the protocol. But in your answer I did not find the difference with my solution, if I'm not mistaken. Is it possible to use ```concept```/```requires``` for this case?

Comment: @Kosterio I'd template more like `template <typename Socket>
class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session<Socket>> {` then. If you need help figuring out details from there - I'm happy to help if you post more self-contained code  (to the edited comment: yes, I suppose you would be happy with the `AsyncReadStream` and `AsyncWriteStream` concepts)

Comment: @sehe yes, just ```typename Socket``` is working solution, but I would like to specify that this is ```basic_stream_socket```, with any proto and executor.

Comment: I think you could - and should - just specify the required concept. Which is `AsyncStream` (that's a Beast name for both `AsyncReadStream` and `AsyncWriteStream`). You don't need to know how it's implemented. In fact, that would just prevent you from writing tests or e.g. using it with files, pipes, SSL streams, serial ports etc.

Comment: Besides the ```socket_.get_executor()``` call I will use ```async_read_some``` and ```async_write``` methods in awaitable ```reader``` method. All of it will work and with only ```<typename Socket>```, but I assumed that in c++20 I could specify what is the base class of typename in my template, even if it templated also.

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer, I know nothing about asynchronous sessions with boost asio.  But if I understand your question correctly, you want to simplify the creation of `shared_ptr`s to your `Session` class without having to write out complicated template parameters.

In general, you can achieve this with a templated free factory function `create_session`, that can deduce its template parameters from the passed argument like so:

```cpp
#include <memory>

//********************** my very own boost asio implementation **********************//

template <typename Protocol, typename Executor>
struct asio_basic_stream_socket{
    using protocol_type = Protocol;
    using executor_type = Executor;
};

template <typename Protocol, typename Executor>
struct asio_local_stream_protocol_socket : asio_basic_stream_socket<Protocol, Executor> {};

template <typename Protocol, typename Executor>
struct asio_ip_tcp_socket : asio_basic_stream_socket<Protocol, Executor> {};

//********************** Session **********************//

template <typename Protocol, typename Executor>
class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session<Protocol, Executor>> 
{
public:
    using Socket = asio_basic_stream_socket<Protocol, Executor>;

    template <typename S>
    friend auto create_session(S);
private:
    Session(Socket){}
};

template <typename Socket>
auto create_session(Socket s)
{
    using P = typename Socket::protocol_type;
    using E = typename Socket::executor_type;
    using S = Session<P,E>;
    return std::shared_ptr<S>(new S(std::move(s)));
}

//********************** Usage **********************//

int main()
{
    asio_local_stream_protocol_socket<int, bool> x;
    auto session_ptr_x = create_session(x);

    asio_ip_tcp_socket<std::string, double> y;
    auto session_ptr_y = create_session(x);
}
```

Some notes:

- You still have a bit of template mess in the body of `create_session`, but this is hidden away nicely.
- At least for the sake of this minimal example, `Session` does not need to be derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.
- In the example, the constructor of `Session` is private. This is based on the assumption that `Session` instances will only ever be created via the factory function. This is not a requirement of course.

https://godbolt.org/z/qExz4WzKn

Comment: The whole point of `shared_from_this` is that the implementation of the class can get a shared pointer to itself from `this`.

Comment: Yes I understand how `std::shared_from_this` works. I also understand that `std::shared_from_this` is heavily used in the `boost::asio` framework.  I just don't think it is relevant to the question, that's why I uncommented it in the minimal example. In fact, my code is very close to the "best" example from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this, with the exception that the factory function is a free function to simplify the use at the call site - which I thought was at the core of the question.

Comment: Commenting it merely ensure that the one thing it is essential for in the shared "session" pattern doesn't work. Also, you evilly dropped the `public` keyword :/ This could send many a programmer into head-scratchers with unexplainable "bad weak_ptr" exceptions...

Comment: Ah good catch! Also, the template parameters are missing. I will fix this. I will also uncomment as it doesn't hurt.