# How to adapt an async function that requires a copyable callback function to Boost.Asio CompletionToken?

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Here are two functions. They are asynchronous functions. Both have a callback function parameter `cb`.
The function `template_cb` 's callback type is template `Cb`.
The function `std_function_cb` 's callback type is `std::function<void()>`.

```cpp
namespace as = boost::asio;

// BEGIN 3rd party code (I can't modify)
inline
void std_function_cb(as::io_context& ioc, std::function<void()> cb) {
    // pseudo implementation
    as::post(ioc, std::move(cb));
}
// END 3rd party code (I can't modify)
```

Let's assume we can't modify the functions.

Now, I want to adapt the functions to Boost.Asio CompletionToken.
See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_compose.html

The current version of the functions can only be used with callback functions.
But if I adapt the function to the CompletionToken, they can be worked with not only callback functions, but also futures and coroutines.
It flexible.

The following code demonstrates adapted function `async_call`.

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << BOOST_VERSION << std::endl;
    {
        std::cout << "token as callback" << std::endl;
        as::io_context ioc;
        async_call(
            ioc,
            [] {
                std::cout << "cb called" << std::endl;
            }
        );
        ioc.run();
    }
    {
        std::cout << "token as future" << std::endl;
        as::io_context ioc;
        std::future<void> f = async_call(ioc, as::use_future);
        std::thread th {[&] { ioc.run(); }};
        f.get();
        std::cout << "future unblocked" << std::endl;
        th.join();
    }
}
```

So I tried it.

I wrote the following adaptation code. But I got compile error.

You can see the complete code and compile error message at https://godbolt.org/z/qxYfGM7hd

It seems that the error is caused by `self` is movable but not copyable. However, `std::function` requires copyable.

```cpp
struct async_impl {
    as::io_context& ioc_;
    enum { first, second } state_ = first;

    template <typename Self>
    void operator()(Self& self) {
        switch (state_) {
        case first:
            state_ = second;
            std_function_cb(ioc_, std::move(self));
            break;
        case second:
            self.complete();
            break;
        }
    }
};

template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_call(
    as::io_context& ioc,
    CompletionToken&& token
)
-> 
typename as::async_result<
    typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
    void()
>::return_type {
    return 
        as::async_compose<
            CompletionToken,
            void()
        >(async_impl{ioc}, token);
}
```

I've checked [move_only_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function) and [unique_function](https://naios.github.io/function2/). I guess they work well with CompletionToken adaptor code.
However, I can't modify `std_function_cb` parameter type.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm missing the point of the question. If `template_cb` works, what is the added value of forcing it to work with `std_function_cb` instead?

Comment: I didn't explain about that. std_function_cb is given by third party. I can't modify callback type. I thought it is enough to describe my restriction. But I try to explain why std_function_cb has std::function<void()> type.
std_function_cb might store cb into the internal queue. The queue needs to fixed type. e.g. std::queue<std::function<void()>>. So  std_function_cb 's callback type is std::function<void()> type. Even if the function interface could modify to the template, the issue still exist in the body of std_function_cb.

Comment: Do you mean that, contrary to the code you provide, `template_cb` doesn't actually exist in your 3rd-party code? You should delete it then.

Comment: I updated the question based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Replace

```cpp
            std_function_cb(ioc_, std::move(self));
```

with

```cpp
            std_function_cb(
                ioc_, 
                [spself = std::make_shared<Self>(std::move(self))] {
                    (*spself)();
                }
            );
```

then works well with std_function_cb.

The problem was `self` is NOT copyable but `std::function` requires copyable. So somehow making `self` copyable, then problem is solved.
I introduced shared_ptr to wrap `self`. The wrapped variable is `spself` (shared_ptr of `self`).
Then passing a lambda function to meet callback signature and capture `spself` to keep its lifetime during async operation.

My solution requires memory allocation because I use shared_ptr. I guess that it is not avoidable but if better solution exists, I'd like to know.

Complete code is https://godbolt.org/z/3b7ro6nxa

Comment: Mmm. I hope the pseudo code (posting to an execution context) is not actually what is being done, because type-erasing the handler type like this will break executor-associated handlers in ASIO (as well as allocator-associated handlers, but that's a performance problem, less than a correctness problem). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71475533/boostasiobind-executor-does-not-execute-in-strand/71475865#71475865

Comment: Thanks. I read the suggested link. I understand that if the library accepts user's handle chain that is associated to the specific executor (e.g. strand) , std::function cannot be used because information is lost. I updated example1 https://godbolt.org/z/PnxPT7xGK line 57-67 would help to understand what I mean. If I want to store the handle (e.g. queing) type erased callable is required but std::function is not a good choice. I should use ErasedHandler (and Afterthoughts function call operator if I need).  Am I understand correctly?

Comment: The comment above (by me) is not good. Finally, I understand that if the function has the parameter `std::function` as callback, users shouldn't pass executor binded handler. Users need to assume that executor is ignored. If users want to execute the body of callback on the specific executor, then capture the executor (when the callback function is a lambda expression) and call boost::asio::dispatch with the executor in the body of lambda expression.

Comment: Yup. I'd summarize it as that too. The elegance of Asio is that it can be optimized using the associated-executor information, but it comes at the cost of interface complexity that not all the users might understand. The best choice(s) depend on the target audience for that reason.