# Why use boost::bind instead of direct function call in boost.asio operations?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I've noticed 3 main options to call handler for async operations in Boost.Asio:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  void doReadFromSocket(); //implementation options provided below. 

 private:
  void handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                  std::size_t bytesTransferred) {
    // ... handle async_read result.
   }
  
  boost::asio::streambuf m_buffer;  
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
}
```

**Option 1** - use lambda function:

```
void MyClass::doReadFromSocket() {
      boost::asio::async_read(m_socket, m_bufferIn, 
                              boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                              [this](const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                                     std::size_t bytesTransferred) {
                                     // ...
                                     }
     }
```

<s>**Option 2** - use direct member function call:</s> UPD. The option is not correct, as pointed out in the comments.

```
void MyClass::doReadFromSocket() {
boost::asio::async_read(m_socket, m_bufferIn, 
                       boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                       handleRead);
}
```

**Option 3** - use boost::bind to call member function that handles the read:

```
void MyClass::doReadFromSocket() {
     boost::asio::async_read(m_socket, m_bufferIn,
                             boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), 
                             boost::bind(&MyClass::handleRead, this, _1, _2));
   }
}
```

The main questions are:

1. Are there any differences in those ways to handle the read operation, especially in terms of performance?
2. Why do we need `boost::bind` to handle the read? Why not use a direct member function call? A lot of examples in the boost library use `boost::bind` to handle async operations. Also, this option seems the least convenient from my perspective

Comment: The third argument to `async_read` is a *handler*. `async_read` calls the handler when the read operation is complete, and passes it values that are produced by said operation. It is not quite clear what is your game plan with the direct call of the handler. What exactly should it do before the read operation is even started? `boost::bind` is one way to create a handler, there are others. We don't *need* `boost::bind`, we need to pass a handler.

Comment: Option 2 looks to be *incorrect*, because you don't supply `this` anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like others said, not all of your options are correct. Looking beyond that:

- `bind` (`std` or `boost`) has the added effect of returning a bind-expression templated on the original functor type. In C++ this means that the original associated namespaces for ADL still apply to the bound handler. This property is important when e.g. the associated executor, allocator or cancellation slot are important (like, a strand).

  The inverse of this is a common pitfall, e.g. when using `std::function<>` instead of a bind expression: [boost::asio::bind_executor does not execute in strand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71475533/boostasiobind-executor-does-not-execute-in-strand)
- boost::bind has the advantage of being available on C++03 (which Asio supports)
- lambdas have a slight benefit of reducing the number of explicit functions defined, at the cost of increased complexity; especially the lifetime of captured variables can be harder to check.

  Also note that you might still need to manually associate an executor (`asio::bind_executor`) with some lambda handlers.

  The reason I feel lambdas have become more viable in generic Asio code is because in "recent" Asio versions [IO objects are constructed from a specific executor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#:%7E:text=Added%20custom%20I/O%20executor%20support%20to%20I/O%20objects), which **will** be the default executor for completion handlers passed to `async_` initiation functions on these IO objects.

Note though that this scratches the surface of options. Contrary to what some people commented, the "handler" argument is *not* necessarily a handler. It's actually what's known as a [completion Token](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html). It can be many things, like `use_future`, `use_awaitable`, `deferred`, `detached`, `as_tuple(another_token)` etc.

Also, there are design patterns where the handler itself is a class - e.g. [derived from `asio::coroutine`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/coroutine.html). This is often used inside the library because it provides a very lightweight way to provide "faux coroutine"-like state machines to implement asynchronous operations in a way that's compatible with C++03 and all completion tokens, without incurring unnecessary overhead.

Also note that many libraries use convenience helpers (like `beast::bind_front_handler`) to reduce the amount of repeated code for bind expressions.

#### To Summarize

It's up to you, based on specific requirements and personal preference. Asio is a highly generic framework for asynchronous operations and you have choices on how you interact with it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge! Appreciated it.