Save boost asio async operation completion handler
I need to implement custom asynchronous operation using boost asio library. The operation itself will be performed by a 3rd-party library.
Approach, which I'm following is:

start async operation via boost::asio::async_initiate. For this I'm implementing initiating function
Store async completion handler, which is passed by boost::asio::async_initiate to the initiating function
Start 3rd-party async operation
Exit initiating function.
According to the boost reference initiating function should be non-blocking.
When async operation completes, invoke previously stored async completion handler

The code, replicating this is below. 3rd-party library here is simulated with a separate thread and boolean flag:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/co_spawn.hpp>

std::atomic<bool> asyncOpStarted = false;

using signature = void(std::string);
std::function<signature> completionHandler;

// Dummy implementation to simulate the async operation
void start_operation()
{
    asyncOpStarted = true;
    std::cout << "Async operation starting..." << std::endl;
}

void do_async_loop()
{
    while (!asyncOpStarted) {
        // sleep & check if operation started
        std::cout << "Waiting for async start..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    };

    std::cout << "Async operation started..." << std::endl;
    // simualate delay
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Async operation finished. Invoke completion handler..." << std::endl;
    completionHandler("Done");
}

// Async operation implementation
template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_do_operation(boost::asio::io_context& io, CompletionToken&& token)
{  
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, signature>(
        [&](auto&& handler) {
            // I need to store "handler" here

            // This doesn't work. std::function<...> requires handler to be copyable:
            //completionHandler = [h = std::move(handler)](std::string res) mutable {
            //    h(res);
            //};

            start_operation();
        }, 
        std::move(token)
    );
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(do_async_loop);

    boost::asio::io_context io;
    
    boost::asio::co_spawn(io, [&]() -> boost::asio::awaitable<void> {
        try {
            // Use `boost::asio::use_awaitable` as the completion token
            auto result = co_await async_do_operation(io, boost::asio::use_awaitable);
            std::cout << "Coroutine: " << result << std::endl;
        } catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "Exception caught" << std::endl;
        }
    }, boost::asio::detached);

    // Run the io_context to process async events
    io.run();
  
}


I'm failing at step (2). Cannot store completion handler in any way.
I tried the following:

Use std::function and move completion handler into capture list
That didn't work because std::function requires handler to be copyable
Create shared pointer to the completion handler, which then could be captured to lambda.
Store completion handler into a variable directly.

So, my questions are:

Am I implementing the integration in a right way at all?
If yes, what is the designed approach in boost asio to store completion handler while operation is running?

Thanks in advance.

std::move_only_function

That might be an option. But this needs to get working with C++20. Sadly move_only_function is coming with C++23

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/boost/asio/detail/executor_function.hpp ... asio has a lightweight one for internal use, in short just use a shared_ptr to the handler if you must use std::function, it is not hard to write a 10 lines move-only type-erased wrapper for the handler.

std::move_only_function can work, but Asio added a specialized type-erasing handler type. It's not trivial @AhmedAEK, so don't invent your own unless you have to

@sehe it depends on how much features you have and how fast you need it, move_only_function is the best as it has 1 indirection on function call, while any_completion_handler has 2 indirections, and in 10 lines you can write one with 2 or 3 indirections.

@AhmedAEK But it loses all associated executor/allocator semantics! See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71475865/85371 - this could lead to serious bugs.

You can use the relatively new asio::any_completion_handler type-erasing container.
Here's a simplified version that also fixes some things:

std::forward instead of std::move
missing std::move on the synthesized handler (in async_initiate)
missing thread join
not juggling references to execution context, instead decoupling that by passing executors (or even detecting the current coroutine's executor).

Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

std::atomic<bool> asyncOpStarted = false;

using signature = void(std::string);
asio::any_completion_handler<signature> completionHandler;

// Dummy implementation to simulate the async operation
void start_operation() {
    asyncOpStarted = true;
    std::cout << "Async operation starting..." << std::endl;
}

void do_async_loop() {
    while (!asyncOpStarted) {
        // sleep & check if operation started
        std::cout << "Waiting for async start..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    };

    std::cout << "Async operation started..." << std::endl;
    // simualate delay
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Async operation finished. Invoke completion handler..." << std::endl;
    completionHandler("Done");
}

template <typename Token> //
auto async_do_operation(asio::any_io_executor ex, Token&& token) {
    return asio::async_initiate<Token, signature>(
        [&](auto&& handler) {
            completionHandler =                                         //
                [w = make_work_guard(ex), handler = std::move(handler)] //
                (std::string res) mutable                               //
            {                                                           //
                std::move(handler)(std::move(res));
            };

            start_operation();
        },
        std::forward<Token>(token));
}

asio::awaitable<void> coro() try {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    std::cout << "Coroutine: " << co_await async_do_operation(ex, asio::deferred) << std::endl;
} catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "Exception caught" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(do_async_loop);

    asio::io_context io;

    co_spawn(io, coro, asio::detached);

    io.run();

    t.join();
}

Output:
Waiting for async start...
Async operation starting...
Async operation started...
Async operation finished. Invoke completion handler...
Coroutine: Done


Thanks for the answer. And for the additional recommendations. Just curious, what is the reason to wrap handler into std::move(...) in this line: std::move(handler)(std::move(res)); ?

In general, Asio handlers can be move-only ("A completion handler is a user-provided, move-only function object that will be invoked, at most once, with the result of the asynchronous operation"). Technically call operator()(...)&& may be rvalue-ref qualified. Even better would be std::forward<decltype(handler)>(handler) come to think of it.

If you don't need the work-tracking, you might simplify to https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e960cad1b5c50430

Brilliant solution for one-time callee!

if handler should be invoked as std::forward<decltype(handler)>(handler)(...), then, I guess, it should also be captured in lambda via perfect forwarding: handler = std::forward<decltype(handler)>(handler) ?

Indeed. It's one of the rare cases where sometimes I feel the urge to use a macro... #define FWD(x) std::forward<decltype(x)>(x) or something
